# First app start failed if there are some events in event store

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, resolvejs

I started an app with some events in event store. As I understand, read model building starts on first read model request. But of course on first start it is no ready yet, but state is returned instantly. So on the client side on each first page open after a server refresh I have an incorrect state that break down my client app.

My question is how can I avoid getting stale data on the client if read model is still being rebuilt?

Comment: I do not see the question. please re-formulate your query so that the question is clear, and include any work / progress you have done to try to solve it already.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, reSolve read model has no information if it is still building, therefore query resolver just use the current state of the read model, whatever it is.

Currently there is no way to wait for rebuild to finish, or to throw an error.

We've recorded an [issue](https://github.com/reimagined/resolve/issues/833) and will fix this in the future release.